# '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>' django error

Tags: python, django, powershell, django-testing

I have been receiving the error below, whenever I wish to run the server (python manage.py runserver)

However as of late, I have been getting the error below.

The last thing that I did was carry out tests for my project over a week ago.

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
 File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
   fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
   autoreload.raise_last_exception()
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
   raise _exception[1]
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
   autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
   fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
   apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
   app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
   module = import_module(entry)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters'
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
   main()
 File "manage.py", line 17, in main
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
   self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
   super().execute(*args, **options)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
   output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 96, in handle
   self.run(**options)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 103, in run
   autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 613, in run_with_reloader
   start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 598, in start_django
   reloader.run(django_main_thread)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 313, in run
   self.run_loop()
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 319, in run_loop
   next(ticker)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 359, in tick
   for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 375, in snapshot_files
   for file in self.watched_files():
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 274, in watched_files
   yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
   return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
 File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 141, in iter_modules_and_files
   resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
 File "C:\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 1177, in resolve
   s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
 File "C:\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 200, in resolve
   return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue as shown above?

A few days ago, I let run these automatic updates on my admin power shell terminal.

I believe this allowed it self to update versions of individual software packages, will I have to use something docker, to create a virtual environment for version control of my project?

Comment: Can you try running the makemigrations and migrate command and then run the server again . work ?

Comment: Yes, however I am getting another error saying "ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'django_filters' .  I will update the question

Comment: did you try 'pip install django-filter'  ?

Comment: Yeah, I did, then pip install all the other modules. Now it works. apologies on my side. thanks